# Installed NVIDIA Drivers, now laptop won't boot, stuck on black screen

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, dell

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and am pretty ticked off. I don't know what's gone wrong, but this is the second time my system has gone AWOL after trying to update NVIDIA drivers. I've got a GeForce 3050 in my Dell XPS 15 and am trying to use my GPU when running a python script.

When I install the NVIDIA driver through [the NVIDIA website](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx) I'm prompted to reboot to have the changes take effect.

Upon getting past the Dell Logo, I get a range of messages (below) but I'm not sure what any of them are for, nor can I make sense of other posts I've seen about how to fix them.

I've got a bunch of important school stuff on my laptop so if anyone could even suggest something that would be a massive help. Thanks in advance.

```
pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid

pci 0000:00:07.1: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid

/dev/nvem0n1p2: recovering journal

/dev/nvem0n1p2: clean, 670359/31227904 files, 118560928/124895488 blocks

dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature

Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02

ACPI BIOS Error (bug):Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND

ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: Don't use the drivers from the NVIDIA site.  Use the drivers from the Ubuntu repos instead.  The drivers from the NVIDIA site do not come DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) ready where it will install the drivers automatically into the new Kernels when they upgrade.  Remove the one you installed and instead install the one from the repo `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`  Now you might need to boot into the previous Kernel so that you can remove the driver.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance! How can I boot into the previous kernel? And do you know which kernel I should be using? Sorry am new to Ubuntu as of last week

Comment: Hopefully when you start up your system you should see the grub screen.  If not, I think you press the Esc key to bring it up.  You might need to press the key over and over until you see the grub menu.  Then go into the Advanced settings and choose the next one.  The newest Kernel is usually listed as the top Kernel in the grub menu.

Comment: Okay thanks so much @Terrance. I tried booting with 5.19.0.35 which sends me straight to the same black screen with a not-flashing terminal cursor. Kernel 5.19.0.32 gets me to the Ubuntu screen with the little loading circle but it freezes, I've tried both in recovery mode too but same deal. Is there another kernel I can download and try?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Secure Boot in your BIOS?  There is a chance that it might be failing to load the unsigned driver(s).

Comment: @Terrance Just turned off secure boot and got sent to the same black screen :/ no Ubuntu loading screen

Comment: The grub menu also has "recovery" kernel choices, try those, they don't use the proprietary Nvidia drivers.